# C#: Is there a clean pattern for finding the right object combined with using?

Tags: c#, registry, using, null-coalescing-operator

I would like a clean/compact pattern that is exception safe and will properly dispose `rulesKey`, even if something has thrown. This does not appear to be possible with `using` (unless maybe 4 `using`s but that seems so verbose and opening extra resources that I might not even need opened).  What gets me is that this would be so direct/easy in C++. Is there a good solution?

```
{
    RegistryKey rulesKey = null;
    rulesKey = rulesKey ?? Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Wow6432Node\\Company\\Internal\\Product");
    rulesKey = rulesKey ?? Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Company\\Company\\Internal\\Product");
    rulesKey = rulesKey ?? Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Wow6432Node\\Company\\Product");
    rulesKey = rulesKey ?? Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Company\\Product");

    // Code using rulesKey, might throw

    rulesKey.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
using (RegistryKey rulesKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Wow6432Node\\Company\\Internal\\Product")
                                ?? Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Company\\Company\\Internal\\Product")
                                ?? Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Wow6432Node\\Company\\Product")
                                ?? Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Company\\Product"))
{
    //use rulesKey here
}
```

Since

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: What if non of the keys could be opened?

Comment: Since [`OpenSubKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a(v=vs.110).aspx) returns null if it fails, then `rulesKey` will be null if they all failed.

Comment: If none of the keys open, it will be null, which is safe for the `using` statement, at least

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't think of this!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like the following. The example is hard-coded but you could easily load the paths from a file or database or whatever. This would allow you to add additional keys without bloating the using statement. It also hardens against restricted access

```
List<string> keyPaths = GetKeyPaths();
private void DoStuff()
{        
    // key is disposed when leaving using block
    using(var key = OpenFirstAvailableKey())
    {
        if(key == null)
        {
            // handle error
        }

        // do stuff
    }
}

private RegistryKey OpenFirstAvailableKey()
{
    RegistryKey result = null;
    try
    {
        foreach(var key in keyPaths)
        {
            result = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key);
            if(result != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }    
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        // handle or throw        
        throw;
    }

    return result;
}

private List<string> GetKeyPaths()
{
    List<string> paths = new List<string>();
    // Load from db or file or whatever...or just hardcode
    paths.Add("Software\\Wow6432Node\\Company\\Internal\\Product");
    paths.Add("Software\\Company\\Company\\Internal\\Product");
    paths.Add("Software\\Wow6432Node\\Company\\Product");
    paths.Add("Software\\Company\\Product");

    return paths;
}
```